# Perl installed via conda snakemake shell error: Can´t open perl script .. no such file or directory

Tags: shell, perl, anaconda, snakemake

I´m currently writing a snakemake pipeline, for which I want to include a perl script.
The script is not written by me, but from a [github](https://github.com/ArimaGenomics/mapping_pipeline) page. I never worked with perl before.

I installed perl (5.32.1) via conda. I have installed miniconda and am working on my universities unix server.

The code for my perl script rule looks like this:

```
rule r1_filter5end:
input:
    config["arima_mapping"] + "unprocessed_bam/{sample}_R1.sam"
output:
    config["arima_mapping"] + "filtered_bam/{sample}_R1.bam"
params:
conda:
    "../envs/arima_mapping.yaml"
log:
    config["logs"] + "arima_mapping/r1_filter5end/{sample}_R1.log"
threads:
    12
shell:
    "samtools view --threads {threads} -h {input} -b | perl ../scripts/filter_five_end.pl | samtools -b -o {output} 2> log"
```

When I run this I receive the following error:

> Can't open perl script "../scripts/filter_five_end.pl": no such file
> or directory found

From what I learned while researching is that the 1. line of a perl script sets the path to my perl executable. The script I downloaded had the following path:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

And since I use perl installed via conda this is probably wrong. So I set the path to:

```
#!/home/mi/my_user/miniconda3/bin/perl
```

However this did still not work, regardless of if I call

```
perl ../scripts/filter_five_end.pl
```

or

```
../scripts/filter_five_end.pl
```

Maybe it´s just not possible to run perl scripts via snakemake?
Anyone who had encountered this specific similar case?^^

Comment: The problem is not with the shebang. The interpreter path in the shebang doesn't matter because you're calling it with `perl ../path` directly. The shell that this command is executed in will resolve the path to the `perl` program (which is very likely the conda one) and then run the script, only taking flags (like `-T` or `-w`) from the shebang inside the script. The error message means it cannot find the actual script file. I suspect when you run that shell command, it's in the wrong directory. Try a fully qualified path.

Comment: Holy frick, why does it always have to be the obvious mistake. I forgot that snakemake always looks files up from the Snakemake file not the directory the rules are saved in. God, 1 whole day. But anyways thank you very much! :)

Comment: I assume that means we should close this question then?

Comment: These things happen to all of us. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with the shebang. The interpreter path in the shebang doesn't matter because you're calling it with `perl ../path` directly. The shell that this command is executed in will resolve the path to the `perl` program (which is very likely the conda one) and then run the script, only taking flags (like `-T` or `-w`) from the shebang inside the script.

The error message means it cannot find the actual script file. I suspect when you run that shell command, it's in the wrong directory. Try a fully qualified path.

As stated [by OP in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73288514/perl-installed-via-conda-snakemake-shell-error-can%C2%B4t-open-perl-script-no-suc?noredirect=1#comment129432867_73288514):

> I forgot that snakemake always looks files up from the Snakemake file not the directory the rules are saved in.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer but perhaps relevant:

> I forgot that snakemake always looks files up from the Snakemake file not the directory the rules are saved in.

This is not entirely correct, I think. The reference point is the directory set by `-d/--directory` which by default is where you execute snakemake:

```
--directory DIR, -d DIR
    Specify working directory (relative paths in the snakefile will use this as their origin). (default: None)
```